# Selenium overlay button cannot be clicked

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am having some issues with one website's button.
Here is my driver function.

```
def get_driver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#     options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = ChromeDriverManager().install(),     chrome_options = options)
    driver.get('https://online.depo-diy.lt')
    return driver

driver = get_driver()
```

Problem is that I cannot select and click anything from the drop down manu when I start my driver. Website request to select a store and then you can press **OK** to proceed.
I check for iframes with `driver.window_handles` but it shows only one frame. This seems like overlay, but I don't know what to do with it.

Only button I can find is `"//button[@class='ms-Button-flexContainer flexContainer-51']"`.
Here is the screenshot, don't know how to copy HTML output..
[image]
Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ModalFocusTrapZone30")))
driver.find_element(By.ID, "Dropdown31-option").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(text(), 'Šilutės 28B, Klaipėda')]").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[@data-automationid='splitbuttonprimary']//span[text()='OK']").click()
```

Comment: Got error on second line: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="Dropdown31-option"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=107.0.5304.107)

Comment: I checked again this code, it works perfectly fine, check the pop-up appears or not.

Comment: You have to add the above code after launching the URL - after this line - ' driver.get('https://online.depo-diy.lt')'